# How to get username password stored in Jenkins credentials separately in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've stored username and password as credentials in jenkins. Now I would like to use them in my Jenkinsfile.

I am using `withCredentials` DSL, however, I'm not sure how to get the username password as separate variables so I can use them in my command.

This is what I'm doing:

```
withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'mycreds', variable: 'MYCREDS')]) {
  sh 'cf login some.awesome.url -u <user> -p password'
}
```

How can I the username and passwork separately? I tried doing `${MYCREDS.split(":")[0]}` but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the `UsernamePasswordMultiBinding` to get credential data in separate values:

```java
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId:'mycreds',
  usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']
])
```

So the following should work in your case:

```java
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId:'mycreds', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
  sh 'cf login some.awesome.url -u $USERNAME -p $PASSWORD'
}
```

Answer (score 73):

Here is a tiny bit simpler version of StephenKing's answer

```java
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'mycreds', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
  sh 'cf login some.awesome.url -u $USERNAME -p $PASSWORD'

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that wasn't possible back then, but nowadays the better choice.

Comment: What is the "credentialsId" used for? In this example when and how could you use the "mycreds" variable?