# How can i read Jenkins pipeline console output during execution using Python Script?

Tags: python, jenkins-pipeline

I have a requirement to read the console output of a previous stage(of the pipeline) during the pipeline execution. The console output from previous stage will be input to a python script, which i am running in the next stage. Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Blue Ocean Plugin, you can retrieve stage-wise console output using [Blue Ocean REST API](https://github.com/jenkinsci/blueocean-plugin/tree/master/blueocean-rest).

A stage in Blue Ocean URL is denoted by a node number when you click that stage. For example, in the URL `.../blue/organizations/jenkins/<job_name>/detail/<job_name>/<build_number>/pipeline/24`, the node number is `24`. This value remains constant for a specific stage in a given pipeline.

Assuming your job has anonymous read permissions, in your downstream pipeline stage you can call a Python script to read the console output of any previous stage.

Sample Python script:

```
import os
import requests
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

current_build_num = os.environ['BUILD_NUMBER']
stage_url = 'https://<jenkins_base_url>/cdf/blue/rest/organizations/jenkins/pipelines/<job_name>/runs/{0}/nodes/<node_number>/log/'.format(current_build_num)
stage_log = requests.get(stage_url, verify=False).content
print(stage_log)
```

Comment: Hi Dibakar, will the field "'BUILD_NUMBER'" be populated in run time?

Comment: Hi Dibakar, with the script you shared i am getting following error- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/shalinigupta/PycharmProjects/first.py/stage.py", line 4, in <module>
    current_build_num = os.environ['BUILD_NUMBER']
  File "C:\Users\shalinigupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'BUILD_NUMBER'                                                                                                                Should i change anything else apart from job name,node number and jenkins URL?

Comment: @shalinigupta
That's correct. The variable `'BUILD_NUMBER'` will be available during run-time. And you only need to substitute `<jenkins_base_url>`, `<job_name>`, and `<node_number>`. I have also updated the script to disable requests warnings by adding `import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)`.

For local testing, you can do, for example `current_build_num = '41'`.

Comment: I am testing the code on PyCharm and I am running Jenkins as 'localhost'. I am getting followingerror:C:\Users\shalini.f.gupta\PycharmProjects\first.py\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/shalini.f.gupta/PycharmProjects/first.py/stage.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shalini.f.gupta\PycharmProjects\first.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked  ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)....is it because the jenkins is using localhost? i am unable to put the entire error here.

Comment: If you are using ‘https://‘ in your URL, try ‘http://‘ instead and vice versa based on your Jenkins server setup. Also, try appending the port number on which Jenkins is running.

Comment: Hi Dibakar, can you also suggest how should i add username and password for Jenkins , in the script?

Comment: You can create a `Username with password credential` in Jenkins and then use the `withCredentials([]){}` directive in your pipeline as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54562772/8895640 and https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/. You can then access the username and password as environment variables in your script.