# Jenkins pipeline - parse logs of specific branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have jenkins pipeline that was build in parallel, and when I go to `"<jenkins_pipeline>/<build_id>/consoleFull"`, I can see logs like that:

```
[branch-1] hi
[branch-2] log11
[branch-3] my logg
           second line of logg
[branch-1] yooo
[branch-2] loggerr
           hii
           hiiiiiii
[branch-1] log line
```

How can I parse logs of specific branch (e.g. branch-2).

I prefer to have the logic in my code, and not to use third-party packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: scripted pipeline

```
node {
    stage('CheckLog') {
      steps {
        def loglist = manager.build.logFile.readLines()
        filteredLog = loglist.grep(~/^branch\-2.*/)

        //< do your stuff >

        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it outside of the jenkinsfile? I prefer to get the logs from python script running on a server

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57751844/how-can-i-read-jenkins-pipeline-console-output-during-execution-using-python-scr/57778982#57778982.

Comment: @jalkjdaasjdlka `filteredLog = filteredLog.join("\n")`;  `writeFile filteredLog`;  <then do your python stuff after job ends>