# how to load jenkins username and password as env vars in a jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

in the Jenkins credentials I have several types of credentials.
One of them, called `my_password` is of the type "Secret Text", in which in a Jenkinsfile, I can access like so:

```
    environment {
        my_env_var = credentials('my_password')
    }
```

Now I created a credential of type "Username with Password" called `user_and_pass` in which I can set up both fields in the same credential.
How can I access both params at the same time, and load them into env variables?
I was thinking something like:

```
    environment {
        my_user = credentials('user_and_pass').someFunctionThatReturnsUser()
        my_pass = credentials('user_and_pass').someFunctionThatReturnsPass()

    }
```

but I don't think it works like that.

Comment: See the [Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment) - when you define a Username and password secret and use the credentials `MYVARNAME = credentials('user_and_pass')` , the `MYVARNAME` will be set to username:password and two additional environment variables will be automatically defined: `MYVARNAME_USR` and `MYVARNAME_PSW `respectively.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, all we have two methods to extract data from credential type `Username and Password`:

1. by the means of Groovy function `withCredentials()`;
2. by the means of helper `credentials()`.

#### withCredentials()

Syntax for extracting creds via `withCredentials`:

```cpp
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'your-credentials-id', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD_VAR', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME')]) {
    // your script could access $PASSWORD_VAR and $USERNAME_VAR
    // as environment variables
    //
    // note: PASSWORD_VAR, USERNAME_VAR is just aliases, you may change it to whatever you like
}
```

If syntax looks too complicated and boring to you, use **Pipeline Snippet Generator** as [follows](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/cloud-secure-guide/injecting-secrets#_using_credentials_and_secrets_in_pipelines).

#### credentials()

Syntax for extracting creds via `credentials()`:

```cpp
environment {
    CREDS = credentials('your-credentials-id')
}
steps {
    // your code can access 
    // username as $CREDS_USR
    // and password as $CREDS_PSW
}
```

#### Which method to use?

It depends on credential type. For `Username and Password` you could use any of the methods - as you like.

`credentials()` helper supports the following types (end of 2022):

- **secret text**;
- **username and password**;
- **secret file**.

For the rest of credentials types you **have to** use `withCredentials()`.

Check out [official docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#for-secret-text-usernames-and-passwords-and-secret-files) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

When you get back the credentials from a ["username and password" secret](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#usernames-and-passwords), you get one string with a username and a password separated by a colon in the format `username:password`.

Check if using **[`usernamePassword`](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.wrapper.CredentialsBindingContext.usernamePassword)** works, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54562772/6309).
It is from the [Jenkins Credentials Binding Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials-binding/).

```
withCredentials(
  [usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'mycreds', 
                    usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', 
                    passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
  sh 'cf login some.awesome.url -u $USERNAME -p $PASSWORD'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins dashboard, Click on Manage Jenkins, Click on Manage Credentials under Security tab, click on system to create Global credentials. This Credential ID (SSH-Centos7 in my case) can be used as below:

```
stage('Example SSH Username with password') {
environment {
    SSH_CREDS = credentials('SSH-Centos7')
}
```

Recent documentation available at [Jenkins official documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment)