# 'pega_db_password' is of type 'Username with password' where 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.StringCredentials' was expected

Tags: jenkins, groovy, devops

I was looking at example of reading a hidden password from Jenkins Credentials plugin and I tried to do this quick example and see how I can now use it in my script.  I got this error

```
'pega_db_password' is of type 'Username with password' where 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.StringCredentials' was expected
```

The script is below:

```
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'pega_db_password', variable: 'pega_db_password')]) {
        sh 'echo $pega_db_password'
      
      }
```

The settings is

[image: WithCredentials Settings]

I have tried to research this and not able to resolve this. I really need to use this just to put the password in a file inside the node agent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get username password stored in Jenkins credentials separately in jenkinsfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43026637/how-to-get-username-password-stored-in-jenkins-credentials-separately-in-jenkins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 changes required:

**1.** Please tick the check box for "**Treat username as secret**"

**2.** Change the pipeline script to something like this:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'pega_db_password', usernameVariable: 'PEGA_DB_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PEGA_DB_PASSWORD')]) {
    sh 'echo $PEGA_DB_PASSWORD' // warning will be thrown by jenkins
  
  }
```

Further examples of credentials plugin for Jenkins can be found [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/).