# How do I add secret file credentials to a job in jenkins casc?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Currently I have a job in my jenkins casc instance which accesses credentials as follows:

```
freeStyleJob('myjob') {
    wrappers {
        credentialsBinding {
            usernamePassword('userVariableName', 'passwordVariableName', 'credential-id')
        }
    }
```

The credentials are provided in casc.yaml

```
credentials:
  system:
    domainCredentials:
    - credentials:
      - usernamepassword:
          scope: GLOBAL
          id: "credential-id"
          username: "user"
          password: "pass123"
          description: "default credentials."
```

However, instead of defining these credentials in casc.yaml, I want to define them in a secret file.

How would I add / access this secret file from my job? Would the content of the secret file be the exact same as the syntax in casc.yaml?

Answer (score 1):

```
  - file:
      id: KUBERNETES_SOME_CONFIG 
      description: your description
      secretBytes: "${readFileBase64:/var/jenkins_home/sshKeys/file.txt}"
      scope: GLOBAL
      fileName: file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! Finally some useful finding on my search as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way in casc:

```
          - usernamePassword:
              id: "aws-credentials"
              description: "AWS Credentials"
              password: "${casc-secret/AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}"
              usernameSecret: true
              username: "${casc-secret/AWS_KEYID}"
```

And relevant content of 2 secret files would be just `<keyid>` & other `<access_key>`.

Or have a look at [usernameColonPassword example](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/).

Also some [good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43026637/how-to-get-username-password-stored-in-jenkins-credentials-separately-in-jenkins) as well.